# python numpy round function strange error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following code from the book python for finance. But the round function from numpy is causing an error like "    return round(decimals, out)
TypeError: round() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"

anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

sp500 = web.DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo',
                            start='1/1/2000', end='4/14/2014')
sp500.info()
sp500['Close'].plot(grid=True, figsize=(8, 5))

sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.rolling_mean(sp500['Close'], window=42), 2)
```

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: It works for me as given, rounds to 2 places. More importantly you are only  providing 2 arguments, quite correctly.

Comment: worked for me as well.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I was using pandas 0.18.0. I changed it back to 0.13.0 and now it worked. do you know why it doesn't work with pandas 0.18.0 ?

Comment: This must be a bug in `pandas` 0.18.0, because with 0.18.0 I get the same issue. Using `pd.rolling_mean(sp500['Close'], window=42).values` gives a rounded numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it seems that in `numpy 1.11.0`, the rounding function looks like this:

```
try:
    round = a.round
except AttributeError:
    return _wrapit(a, 'round', decimals, out)
return round(decimals, out)
```

It looks like `pandas.Series.round` only takes two arguments (`self`, `precision`), but `numpy` is passing it an additional argument, `out`. Presumably this is either a bug or API change in `pandas` or `numpy`.

There are two simple workarounds I can see. The first is to just directly use the `Series.round()` function:

```
sp500['42d'] = pd.rolling_mean(sp500['Close'], window=42).round(2)
```

The other option is to just apply the `numpy.round` function to the underlying numpy array:

```
sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.rolling_mean(sp500['Close'], window=42).values, 2)
```

**Edit**: Looks like this is a known issue. See [the `pandas` github tracker, issue #12644](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12644).